# Passing login credentials to new view

Tags: django

The system uses `django-tenant-schemas` for separating data. The users are all on a shared schema so they can log in from any subdomain. To prevent them from seeing another companies data there is a `middleware.TenantUserRedirectMiddleware` which redirects the user to the proper subdomain after authentication.

The problem is that it wants them to login once again after they get to the correct subdomain. I believe one solution is to get the login data from the `request` object and pass it to `sessions` then use that data to automatically authenticate the user at the subdomain so that they are not asked for credentials a second time. How do I get the login form data from `request`?

I have tried this in the `Middleware`:

```
class TenantUserRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                if request.user.company != request.tenant:
                    print(request.POST) # This is empty, where is the login data?
                    if DEVELOPMENT:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(
                            '//' + request.user.company.get_primary_domain().domain + ':8000/login/')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('//' + request.user.company.get_primary_domain().domain + '/login/')
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Instead of a middleware to redirect to the correct subdomain use a custom authentication backend which will **not even allow** the user to login to the other domain.

Comment: I will look this up. In the custom auth backend will I be able to redirect and login the user automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Since your you are using some multi-tenant solution it is best not to even allow users that try to login to the other subdomains, you can do this by implementing a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). Add this to some file in a suitable app of yours:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class TenantBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user = super().authenticate(request, username, password, **kwargs)
        if user and user.company == request.tenant:
            return user
        return None
```

Now you need to add this to the list `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your settings

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # We replace the below backend by our own
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'yourapp.path_to.TenantBackend',
]
```

Also if you actually want to allow the login to persist over subdomains you can set [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) in the settings like so:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".yourdomain.com"
```

If you do this your user should be successfully redirected to their correct domain with their login persisting (you would keep your `TenantUserRedirectMiddleware` for the redirect).

Comment: The issue I see with this route is that I want to redirect to the correct subdomain and log the user in if they exist. I expect the users to complain about subdomains so I am trying to avoid having them have to remember *exactly* what URL to go to.

Comment: @DavidAlford simply put forward the point that it is insecure. Even if both the subdomains are run from the same server it does not make sense for a user of some other subdomain to log into another subdomain. Also the users browser itself would prevent you from doing any such things.

Comment: The users/companies are on shared schemas. Everything else is tenant specific. Would you mind explaining how it is insecure so I can resolve this issue? The client wants, and the ultimate goal, if for users to be able to log in securely from the main domain and be redirected to the correct subdomain.

Comment: Is this insecure to have the user login on the public domain and then redirect to the private domain and ask for login credentials again?

Comment: @DavidAlford check my edit I have added how you would persist the login over sub-domains.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you see any areas which are a security concern?

Comment: @DavidAlford I am not exactly experienced in security but I believe that logging in from one domain and redirecting would generally require the developers to be more careful in the security aspect. The safest bet would be to simply not allow cross-domain logins unless one knows what they are doing.